# Spring RestTemplate readin JSON Document

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have an elementary question using Spring RestTemplate for reading a JSON document. I make a get call to a URL which returns a JSON document in this format:
{
 {
  ..
 },
{
  ..
 }
}

I couldn't find any examples for fetching this kind of data.. Would be helpful if someone could help me out with this...

Comment: Instead of the superfluous statements that you could not find anything (if you did, you wouldn't be asking here would you?) and that an answer would be helpful (it is to be hoped they would be), it would be much more helpful to include an actual **question** as in a sentence ending in a question mark (?). Especially when an answer to that question would solve your problem. Please update your post accordingly, I already removed the fluff and formatted your code example by indentation (Ctrl+K)

Comment: @Alfasin: Thats the exact format that is being returned from the backend. It's a Firebase DB where there's an option of storing data as an array(the format that you have shown). But storing data as an array has performance implications in Firebase. Hence, I want to store and retrieve the data in the format mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Anthon Well, thanks for the edit.. Would take care of it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem in my case using the firebase-client apis. That exposes a map of values for the kind of json i was talking about. Still, I would like to know how to do this using RestTemplate..